# Return type of Application.Evaluate in exotic cases

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am trying to write a method in C# that will, given the name of a named range in an Excel workbook, retrieve the values in that range.  I'd like it to work even if the named range isn't a pure reference to a range (e.g. `=Sheet1!A1:A10`) but is instead something like `={1,2,3,4,5}` or `=OFFSET(Sheet1!A1:A10,3)`.

I'm doing the following:

```
Excel.Application xl = ...;
Excel.Name name = ...;

object value = xl.Evaluate(name.Value);
// if it's a range, turn it into an object[] or object[,]
if (value is Excel.Range) value = ((Excel.Range)value).Value2;

if (value is object[]) {
    // do stuff
} else if (value is object[,]) {
    // do slightly different stuff
}
```

I had thought that a named range with a value like `={1,2,3,4,5}` would just come out as an `object[]` or `object[,]`, but it doesn't.  `value.GetType()` just reports `System.__ComObject` (edit: now I'm getting `System.Object[*]`, and haven't been able to reproduce `System.__ComObject` - but it still doesn't cast to `object[]`), and I haven't been able to narrow that down any further.

What type should I be casting `value` to?

edit: here is some test code and output.  This may be the simpler question of "what the heck is a `System.Object[*]`, which the vagaries of Google don't permit me to search for.

code:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
            object value = xl.Evaluate("={1,2,3,4,5}");
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.WriteLine(value is object[]);
            Console.WriteLine(value.GetType());
            Console.ReadLine();
            xl.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

> System.Object[*]
>
> False
>
> System.Object[*]

edit2: if I instead evaluate `"={1;2;3;4;5}"` then I get an `object[,]`.  Huh.

Comment: Do you have an exact piece of code (and possibly file) that exhibit this behavior? Evaluate is a very versatile method.

Comment: Looks like an Interop bug to me. Using VBA you can assign Evaluate to a VBA variant and then test the variant. But evaluate is probably actually returning an xlOper data structure which VBA invisibly converts under the covers to a variant. Evaluate is a very quirky method: see http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/

Comment: value is a dynamic type, you get the  value as dynamic "dynamic value = xl.Evaluate(name.Value);" then you can cast it to an expected type later.

Comment: @SimonMourier I posted an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the array created by Excel is not 0-based, but 1-based, you can convert it like this:

```
object[] ints = ((Array)value).ToArray<object>();
```

With this helper method extension:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this Array array)
{
    if (array == null)
        return null;

    if (array.Rank != 1)
        throw new NotSupportedException();

    var newArray = new T[array.GetLength(0)];
    var lb = array.GetLowerBound(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = (T)array.GetValue(i + lb);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

If you use .NET 4, there are chances that the return type of `Evaluate` will be defined as `dynamic`. So with this code:

```
dynamic value = xl.Evaluate("={1,2,3,4,5}"); // or var instead of dynamic
```

You will get a `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]' to type 'System.Object[]`' because the new .NET 4 interop layer will try automatically to create a standard array. So you need to do this instead (like you do in your code):

```
object value = xl.Evaluate("={1,2,3,4,5}");
object[] ints = ((Array)value).ToArray<object>();
```